# Creating a new repository at remote server

Tags: c++, svn, tortoisesvn, commit, remote-server

I am new to SVN , I know the following

```
checkout and commit
```

However since I have important data on my pc I wanted to make a folder on the remote server. I have got the access rights and the url of the server. Meanwhile I did some seaches about making a new folder and commiting all my files there. All I get is how to do it in local machine, however I want to save the important data there, hope some one can help.

The tortoise client is TORTOISESVN 1.7.7.

And please let me know if i can make my PC as a remote server i still do not have a static IP.

Comment: Do you want to do this in a C++ program?

Comment: What is the actual problem? Do you have a remote repository you want to connect to and work with? Do you want to set up a local repository to work with?

Comment: if your actual problem is how to set up the server try this http://www.tonyspencer.com/2007/03/02/setup-a-subversion-server-in-4-minutes/

Comment: There are two problems , first as @juanchopanza said i want to do this in a c++ program , another problem is i want to create a folder at the remote server using SVN(let me know the steps )so that i may implement that in my c++ code

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to use svnadmin from the server (over ssh or similar) to create a repository.

`svnadmin create /path/to/svn/repos/repo_name`

from which you can import and commit code into. I import a 'skeleton directory' (consisting of trunk, branches and tags directories) and then checkout into my working copy.

Technically any machine can have the Subversion server installed. Whether you can be accessed from 'outside' is a different matter. Without a static IP, you'll need somekind of dynamic naming service, like DynDNS.